# Unable to get SMM Dell signature

Tags: 15.04

I have an DELL inspiron 530 and I get this error message in my `dmesg` log

```
[    3.753349] i8k: unable to get SMM Dell signature
```

I can load the module via

```
sudo modprobe i8k force=1
```

How can I do that when the system boots?

---

*Update // So 19. Jul 15:04:24 CEST 2015*

- `lsmod | grep i8k`

  ```
  i8k                    16384  0
  ```
- `cat /sys/module/i8k/parameters/force`

  ```
  cat: /sys/module/i8k/parameters/force: No such file or directory
  ```
- `dmesg | grep i8k`

  ```
  [    3.324621] i8k: unable to get SMM Dell signature
  ```

---

*Update // So 19. Jul 13:24:09 CEST 2015*

- `% cat /etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf`

  ```
  options i8k force=1
  ```
- `% cat /etc/modules`

  ```
  # /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
  #
  # This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
  # at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


  # Generated by sensors-detect on Fri Jul  3 19:44:07 2015
  # Chip drivers
  coretemp
  it87
  i8k
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you write a conf file. You can do so quickly from the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options i8k force=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf
echo i8k  >> /etc/modules
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Same error `% sudo dmesg | grep i8k
[    3.324621] i8k: unable to get SMM Dell signature`

Comment: Is this a temporary informational message? Did the module load nonetheless? `lsmod | grep i8k` Did the parameter apply? `cat /sys/module/i8k/parameters/force`

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: On my 15.04 system running a 4.0 kernel, no parameters appear in /sys aside from power_status, even when force=1 is set. No other parameters available in `modinfo i8k` are shown. However, as you've verified in `lsmod`, the module _did_ load. Is the behavior of the sensors and fans as expected, suggesting that `i8k` is working correctly?