# Ubuntu 16.04 keeps freezing randomly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, freeze

I have a problem after installing Ubuntu 16.04. My system randomly freezes (according to the number of related questions here, it seems more of a bug perhaps.) I tried to use Daniel's solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly). However, I ended up with quite a few errors:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_sig.bin  for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_bl.bin  for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
```

Unlike Daniel, I have quite a lot of items to update/fix. I don't use the nvidia driver as it made the screen go black. Right now I am using the Nouveu driver, which seems to work fine as far as displaying. I am guessing I need to add the firmware listed above but how do I go about that?

Comment: Did you try any of the several other solutions provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly) other than Daniel's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 keep freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly)

Answer (score 1):

New version of [linux-firmware](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/1.158) package might help

> linux-firmware (1.158) yakkety; urgency=medium
>
> Rebase against git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git 8afadbe553017bec1e442b5a9fba859b54fd33fb
>
> ```
> Update Intel OPA hfi1 firmware
>
> nvidia: Add GM200, GM204 and GM206 signed firmware
> ...
> ```

Downloading and inspecting the contents of the file,

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/1.158/+build/9700625/+files/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
dpkg -c linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb | grep gm206/gr/sw_method_init.bin
```

All the missing firmware files are hopefully there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I still see the "Unable to get SMM Dell Signature" when I start up and it is freezing up more now.

Comment: @lee Hopefully your laptop isn't having temperature problems, [this case](http://askubuntu.com/questions/650164/unable-to-get-smm-dell-signature) and others points to that direction.

Comment: I'm not using a laptop -- I'm using a desktop. The only thing I did before installing Ubuntu 16.04 was to add a new primary drive (I kept the previous one as a second drive.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.158 of [linux-firmware](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/1.158) package seems like it will help.

#### Download it:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/1.158/+build/9700625/+files/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
```

#### Install the firmware:

```
dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
```

---

Note that J.J.'s answer doesn't have you actually install the new firmware, only inspect the contents. This will install it.

Source: [dpkg cheatsheet](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php)

Comment: Thanks. However, I had thought I had posted this here. I have since loaded 14.04, using the Nvidia driver and have had great success, no problems.

Comment: @Lee could you post your solution as an answer?